# Finding the value of Antiderivative $F(x)$ at $x=2$, where $f(x)=\frac{x^3+\sin(x)}{x^2+2}$

Tags: calculus

First of all, many thanks for this great website.

Let $F(x)$ be the antiderivative of $$f(x)=\frac{x^3+\sin(x)}{x^2+2}.$$ If $F(5)=\pi$, then what is $F(2)$?

This question was in Calculus exam, I know that $F(x)=\int f(x)\ \mathrm dx +C$, but I am not sure how to integrate the $f(x)$. I divided the integral into two parts, first one was $\int \frac{x^3}{x^2+2} \ \mathrm dx$ which is easy using the long division , but the second part got me stuck which is $\int \frac {\sin(x)}{x^2+2}\ \mathrm dx$. I tried to use integration by parts but no results at all. I used WolframAlpha to find the answer, which  gives a strange answer using complex numbers. I have not studied any complex course so far. So I'm guessing there is another trick here, could anyone help me to find that?

Comment: I don't think there are any tricks here. You have to use special functions or series to find this value.

Comment: By Newton-Leibniz $$
F(2) = \pi  - \int_2^5 {\frac{{x^3  + \sin x}}{{x^2  + 2}}dx}  =  - 5.866664349855 \ldots .
$$ I do not think there is a nice, closed-form expression for this value.

Comment: -Gary May you please specify more details about how you got the result? Thanks.

Comment: @F.Turgut $\int_2^5f(x)\,dx=F(5)-F(2)$ since $F$ is an antiderivative. You can approximate $F(2)$ numerically if you want.